# I wanted to know how can I use a loop to give the marks to students either 1 or 0 in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

This the table in which the calculated marks will be shown in the last Result column... How can I write my program in plpgsql using functions and loops in it so that i can calculate student marks....Also the marks will be checked on the basis of Answered_Correctly as if it is 'Yes' marks given will 1 otherwise 0. Please suggest a solution

```
create table test(User_ID varchar(20) ,
 User_Name varchar(30),
 Question_Number integer,
 Answered varchar(10),
 Answered_Correctly varchar(20),
 Question_Text text,
 Correct_Answer text,
 User_Choice text,
 Result varchar(10)
)
```

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

So, `Result` should be `1` or `0` based on weather the answer was correct or not? Why is it text instead of an `integer`?

Same for `Answered` and `Answered_Correctly` - shouldn't they be `boolean`?

Assuming I understood the question, you don't need PL/pgSQL, just:

```
UPDATE test
  SET result = CASE answered_correctly WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  WHERE result IS NULL;
```